# Middleman + Bourbon error with gem

Tags: middleman

im trying to build a middleman project using bourbon but I'm getting some problems.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
  In Gemfile:
    bourbon (~> 4.0.1) ruby depends on
      sass (~> 3.3) ruby

    neat (>= 0) ruby depends on
      sass (3.2.19)
```

My gemfile:

```
# SASS
gem 'sass', '~> 3.3.7'

#Neat
gem 'neat'

#Bourbon
gem 'bourbon', '~> 4.0.1'
```

Is it not possible to run these things together? (I'm a beginner using ruby for projects).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> neat (>= 0) ruby depends on
>   sass (3.2.19)
> ```

The latest version of Neat, which is 1.6.0, depends on Sass 3.3 and greater. It seems that you've got an older version of Neat in your gemset which Bundler tries to use.

Try running `bundle update`. If it doesn't help, try updating your Gemfile with this:

```
gem 'neat', '~> 1.6.0'
```

Then run `bundle update` again.

To see dependencies and their version of any versions of Ruby gems, visit [RubyGems.org](http://RubyGems.org).

For example, Neat v1.6.0 [lists](http://rubygems.org/gems/neat/versions/1.6.0) lists the following dependencies:

- bourbon >= 3.1
- sass >= 3.3

Answer (score 1):

Use the `gem sass` instead of `gem sass-rails` and also delete the `*= require_tree .` from your app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss.css file.